# Is 90 day notice period standard in India or it raises red flag about company?

Tags: india, notice-period

Is 90 day notice period standard in India or it raises red flag about company? This is for associate business analyst role.

Comment: I would say 3 months is pretty standard all over the world.

Comment: @Jishan I would not say so. I have held jobs in the UK and the US, and never had a notice period longer than one month.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan Depends - a junior dev / employee who can be easily replaced has generally 1 month. A senior, slightly hard to replace ones have 3. I have seen (in EU) people with 6 months notice period as it is apparently very hard to replace top IT talent in Europe.

Comment: @Jishan I had no contracted notice period while I was an architect with 30 years industry experience. I was working for a large company in the US.

Comment: Notice period in the US is almost universally 2 weeks, no more, except in special cases.  But that’s why we have country tags, so people who know something about the actual country at hand can answer instead of assuming they all work alike.

Answer (score 4):

This certainly is not a *red flag*. I have seen notice periods vary based on the "how easy are you / your skills to replace". For example:

1. Junior Developer / Analyst: 1 month
2. Senior Developer / Analyst / Architect: 3 months
3. Management / Team / Country Lead: Even 6 months!

However, make sure the clause is also reciprocated, i.e. if the company wants to replace you, you must have a 3 months window to search for a new job. And hopefully there is a compensation clause for you if they choose to replace you.

Answer (score 3):

Speaking from work experience in India, notice period of 90 days is not uncommon, it's actually the standard practice, irrespective of the role / designation.

Very recently, some organizations are adapting to a shorter notice period of 60 days, but long to go before that becomes the standard.